# Dynamically update gridview.

Tags: c#, html, sql, gridview

I have a gridview that is displayed in a website, the table is currently showing data stored in a database, however the database is constantly getting updated.

Is it possibe to dynamically update the gridview as the database gets updated?

I am using SQL Server and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is the data shared by all users, could it be a static datasource? Is it changed from within your ASP.NET application or from outside? Have a look at th SqlCacheDependency explained here with an example for WPF and ASP.NET: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ASP.NET? If yes, there is no way by which Grid can know about the updates on the data source. If you want to do this, you can try to use AJAX and have some background worker pull data at regular intervals. But this is going to be very insensitive to bandwidth. If its not designed for performance, this might result in bad customer feedback.